# Recursive function that identifies whether string 1 is contained within string 2? (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, string, recursion

Is there a way to write a recursive (**required**) function that takes two strings as parameters and returns True if all characters in the first string can be found, in order, in the second string; and False otherwise?

For example:

```
>>> contains("lit", "litter")
True
>>> contains("thot", "thurtle")
False
>>> contains("ratchet", "ramtbunchiousest")
True
>>> contains("shade", "hadsazie")
False
```

The letters don't need to be consecutive (as in the third example), but they need to be in order (which is why the fourth example fails).

I wrote this code:

```
def contains_recursive(s1, s2):

if s1 == "":
    return True
elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
    return contains_recursive(s1[1:], s2[1:])
elif s1[0] != s2[0]:
    return contains_recursive(s1[0], s2[1:])
else:
    return False

return contains_recursive(s1, s2) == True
```

and it gave out this error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive? Learning sake, homework, or...?

Comment: @croesus without recursion you can use "in" operator ex: result_bool = substring in string

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta - That will return `False` unless the characters are consecutive.

Comment: The problem seems to be here: `elif s1[0] != s2[0]:
    return contains_recursive(s1[0], s2[1:])`. When `s1[0] != s2[0]`, it will call itself recursively, passing `s2[1:]` to `contains_recursive`. When it has run to the point where `s2` is of length 1, it throws an error because `s2[1:]` is out of range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line:

```
 return contains_recursive(s1[0], s2[1:])
```

you are shortening s1 to one character but then at the next call you may hit:

```
 return contains_recursive(s1[1:], s2[1:])
```

with s1 a string of len 1.

You need to use:

```
return contains_recursive(s1, s2[1:])
```

and add a check on the length of s1

Answer (score 1):

I take it that being *recursive* is a requirement. In that case:

```
def contains(s1, s2):
    if not s1:
        return True
    i = s2.find(s1[0])
    if i == -1:
        return False
    else:
        return contains(s1[1:], s2[i+1:])
```

This produces:

```
>>> contains("lit", "litter")
True
>>> contains("thot", "thurtle")
False
>>> contains("ratchet", "ramtbunchiousest")
True
>>> contains("shade", "hadsazie")
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting could be because s2 is an empty string. Add a check for it's length as well. If you reach this point it would mean you haven't found all the letters you are searching for and therefore the end result should be false.

```
if s2 == '':
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using rescurive functions for efficiency.

```
def test(s1, s2):
    idx2 = 0
    for c in s1:
        if c in s2[idx2:]:
            idx2 = s2.index(c) + 1
        else:
            return False

    return True

# Test
lists = [   ("lit", "litter"), 
            ("thot", "thurtle"), 
            ("ratchet", "ramtbunchiousest"), 
            ("shade", "hadsazie")]

result = [test(*t) for t in lists]
print(result)
# Output
[True, False, True, False]
```